# OpenCV with Android Capture Images

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

What is the best way to **capture** images in android and process them with opencv ?
should i use the surface view [As here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-picture) or i should use the opencv camera as in opencv samples ? and how can i load the captured image and convert it  to Mat?
Thanks in advance

```
 private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d("E",
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions ");
            return;
        }

        try {

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            //processImage();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("E", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("E", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: For what opencv is used?

Comment: it is  Open source Computer Vision used for image processing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the OpenCV samples there is a CameraBridgeViewBase that helps in capturing, processing and showing the results of the camera preview (continuous stream of lower resolution images).

If you want to process a single capture with more resolution, you should use something similar to onPictureTaken(). Then you can read the image using [Highgui.imread()](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html#imread%28java.lang.String%29) and process it.

You could also avoid writing and reading to a file by creating a Bitmap from the data array with [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) and then converting the Bitmap to a Mat using [Utils.bitmapToMat()](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/android/Utils.html#bitmapToMat%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20org.opencv.core.Mat%29)