# android with opencv - Feature match in real time

Tags: android, opencv

I want to write an Android App that can track object with OpenCV features matching in real time.
For now, I can features matching with two pictures, I want it can work in real time, even the camera frames will be pretty low, I still want to try it.
Any help、suggestion or references for me?

**Edit:**
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246528/opencv-android-background-subtraction) and I try it like this

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();

    VideoCapture  mcapture = new VideoCapture(0);
        mcapture.open(Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME);
        if(!mcapture.isOpened()){
            Core.putText(mRgba, "Capture Fail", new Point(50, 50), BIND_AUTO_CREATE, BIND_AUTO_CREATE, Color_Green);
        }else{
        Mat frame = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, frame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        mcapture.retrieve(frame, 3);
        mRgba = frame;

        }
    return mRgba;

}
```

VideoCapture is not open . any help?

Comment: Have you tried using the cv::VideoCapture class to get the frames from the camera capture or maybe something similar to what was suggested in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218844/opencv-with-android-capture-images)..? Once you have the frames, you can simply plug in your existing program to the capture sequence.

HTH

Comment: I tried use VideoCapture in my case for few day, but I'm still not try it out, and don't understand how it works, I need more help, and I'm still working on it . Thanks !

Comment: I was try use VideoCapture , but I can't change Javacameraview to nativecameraview ,even OpenCV sample tutorial1 ,I'm working on it ...

Answer (score 0):

I found [this tutorial](http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-updated-for-opencv-2-4-6/) which explains eye tracking using Android.. You can just follow this to use the main camera and track objects..

HTH